# How can I convert an OData QueryNode to a LINQ expression?

Tags: linq, odata

This is what I want to achieve:

1. Get a filter expression from `ODataQueryOptions.Filter.FilterClause.Expression`
2. Use a visitor to copy and adjust the filter expression
3. Use something similar to `ODataQueryOptions.ApplyTo(IQueryable query)` to apply the *modified* filter expression to an IQueryable.

Is there maybe some helper in any of the Microsoft OData libraries to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to code in [FilterBinder](https://github.com/OData/WebApi/blob/master/OData/src/System.Web.OData/OData/Query/Expressions/FilterBinder.cs).